# How do I open a file with the name of "Key.data" using 'gfptrkey' variable?

Tags: c, file, input, file-io, global-variables

Here are the global variables, and one of them is gfptrKey.

```
#include "Header.h"

// Global Variables
unsigned char gkey[65537];
unsigned char* gptrKey = gkey;          // used for inline assembly routines, need to access this way for Visual Studio
char gPassword[256] = "SECRET";
unsigned char gPasswordHash[32];
unsigned char* gptrPasswordHash = gPasswordHash;    // used for inline assembly routines, need to access this way for Visual Studio
unsigned char gdebug1, gdebug2;

FILE* gfptrIn = NULL;
FILE* gfptrOut = NULL;
FILE* gfptrKey = NULL;
char gInFileName[256];
char gOutFileName[256];
char gKeyFileName[256];
int gOp = 0;            // 1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt
int gNumRounds = 1;
```

Already have functions to open the input file and output file for the main.

```
FILE* openInputFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* fptr;
    long sz;

    fptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nError - Could not open input file %s!\n\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(fptr);
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (sz == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error - File size is zero for \"%s\".\n\n", filename);
        fprintf(stderr, "Aborting operation - try again!\n\n");
        fclose(fptr);
        exit(0);
    }

    return fptr;

} // openInputFile

FILE* openOutputFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* fptr;

    fptr = fopen(filename, "wb+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nError - Could not open output file %s!\n\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return fptr;

} // openOutputFile
```

Here are the other 2 functions in case if there is an error:

```
void usage(char* argv[])    //   cryptor.exe -e -i <input file> –k <keyfile> -p <password> [–r <#rounds>]
{
    printf("\n\nUsage:\n\n");

    printf("To Encrypt:\n");
    printf("%s -e <message_filename> -k <keyfile> -p <password> [-r <#rounds>]\n\n", argv[0]);

    printf("To Decrypt:\n");
    printf("%s -d <message_filename> -k <keyfile> -p <password> [-r <#rounds>]\n\n", argv[0]);

    printf("-e filename     :encrypt the specified file\n");
    printf("-d filename     :decrypt the specified file\n");
    printf("-p password     :the password to be used for encryption [default='password']\n");
    printf("-r <#rounds>        :number of encryption rounds (1 - 3)  [default = 1]\n");
    printf("-o filename     :name of the output file [default='encrypted.txt' or 'decrypted.txt'\n\n");
    printf("The order of the options is irrelevant.\n\n");
    exit(0);
} // usage

void parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int cnt;
    char ch;
    bool i_flag, o_flag, k_flag, p_flag, err_flag;

    i_flag = k_flag = false;                // these must be true in order to exit this function
    err_flag = p_flag = o_flag = false;     // these will generate different actions

    cnt = 1;    // skip program name
    while (cnt < argc)
    {
        ch = *argv[cnt];
        if (ch != '-')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "All options must be preceeded by a dash '-'\n\n");
            usage(argv);
        }

        ch = *(argv[cnt] + 1);
        if (0)
        {
        }

        else if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E')
        {
            if (i_flag == true || gOp != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed an input file - can't encrypt/decrypt multiple files.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }

            i_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-e'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }

            strncpy(gInFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
            gOp = 1;    // encrypt
        }

        else if (ch == 'd' || ch == 'D')
        {
            if (i_flag == true || gOp != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed an input file - can't decrypt/encrypt multiple files.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }

            i_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-d'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }

            strncpy(gInFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
            gOp = 2;    // decrypt
        }

        else if (ch == 'o' || ch == 'O')
        {
            if (o_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed an output file.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            o_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-o'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gOutFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'k' || ch == 'K')
        {
            if (k_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed a key file.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            k_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-k'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gKeyFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'p' || ch == 'P')
        {
            if (p_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed a password.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            p_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must enter a password after '-p'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gPassword, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'r' || ch == 'R')
        {
            int x;

            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must enter number between 1 and 3 after '-r'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            x = atoi(argv[cnt]);
            if (x < 1 || x > 3)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Warning! Entered bad value for number of rounds. Setting it to one.\n\n");
                x = 1;
            }
            gNumRounds = x;
        }

        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! Illegal option in argument. %s\n\n", argv[cnt]);
            usage(argv);
        }

        cnt++;
    } // end while

    if (gOp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Encrypt or Decrypt must be specified.\n\n)");
        err_flag = true;
    }

    if (i_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! No input file specified.\n\n");
        err_flag = true;
    }

    if (k_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! No key file specified.\n\n");
        err_flag = true;
    }

    if (p_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning! Using default 'password'.\n\n");
    }

    if (o_flag == false && err_flag == false)   // no need to do this if we have errors
    {
        strcpy(gOutFileName, gInFileName);
        if (gOp == 1)   // encrypt
        {
            strcat(gOutFileName, ".enc");
        }
        if (gOp == 2)   // decrypt
        {
            strcat(gOutFileName, ".dec");
        }
    }

    if (err_flag)
    {
        usage(argv);
    }
    return;
} // parseCommandLine
```

and here is the main function I was trying to figure out how to open the file using 'gfptrKey' variable, and the name of file is "Key.data".

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int length; // resulti;

//  fprintf(stdout, "\n\nCrypto Order:%s\n\n", CRYPTO_ORDER);

    // parse command line parameters
    parseCommandLine(argc, argv);       // sets global variables, checks input options for errors

    // open the input and output files
    gfptrIn = openInputFile(gInFileName);    // reading the file
    gfptrKey = openInputFile(gKeyFileName);  // reading the keyfile data
    gfptrOut = openOutputFile(gOutFileName); // writing the file


    length = fread(gkey, 1, 65537, gfptrKey);
    if (length != 65537)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Length of key file is not at least 65537.\n\n");
        exit(-1);

    }

    fclose(gfptrKey);
    gfptrKey = NULL;

    if (gOp == 1)   // encrypt
    {
        encryptFile(gfptrIn, gfptrOut);
    }
    /*else
    {
        decryptFile(gfptrIn, gfptrOut);
    }*/

    fclose(gfptrIn);
    fclose(gfptrOut);

    return 0;
} // main
```

But what I need is Input File for "Key.data" by using gfptrKey variable, not the Output file.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. What exactly isn't working? It looks like you're calling your function to open the file just like you've described you want to.

Comment: It's actually working, but what I'm having problem is I can't find a way to open the input file using the name of "Key.data" and gfptrKey variable.

Comment: So how about `strcpy(gInFileName,"Key.data");  gfptrKey = gInFileName;  gfptrIn = openInputFile(gfptrKey);`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is that your code? It seems that you need to call your program with `-k` parameter providing file name. What happens if you do that? What is not working in your program?

Comment: Why does `unsigned char gkey[65537]` need to be so large.`?

Comment: @ryyker That's what my teacher wants for the project assignment.

Comment: @Gerhardh My teacher is the one who sent me the code so I can activate my assembly code. Whenever I run the program, the console application pops out and says "Error! No key file specified. Warning! Using default 'password'", then I was trying to figure out and finding the way to open the key file ("Key.data"), but I couldn't how.

Comment: If you got that error message it is easy to find the location where it is printed and go backward to see where the condition variable would be set. Did you provide the -k parameter? Are you aware that the message about default passwort is independent from the key? How do you call your application, i.e. what have you tried so far to solve the problem?